# Как в angular 4 делать маску для инпута?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Здравствуйте, к сожалению никак не могу найти как делать маску тектсового инпута в ангуляре, примерно надо сделать такое

https://codepen.io/marcomafessolli/pen/akEEYR но в ангуляре от 2й версии
Возможно есть библиотеки для этого, или может нативными инструментами такое можно сделать?

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

```
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть код на JS, можете использовать его или воспользоваться алгоритмом и написать на TypeScript. А если вы хотите использовать сторонние компоненты, то советую посмотреть в сторону [Angular2-text-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask)